# Passenger Phusion sub-uri with Apache HTTPD without virtualHost Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, httpd.conf

Trying to deploy my application to a sub-uri. such as, [IP ADDRESS]/sub-domain instead of just [IP address].  so, the instructions at passenger assume that you have a virtualhost already established in your code (https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri).  Does anybody know how to get this working with the latest version of Passenger and Rails in the HTTPD config file?